# Where to set "os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']='0'" for reproducible results in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, reproducible-research

I want to train a CNN in Google Colab and try to get reproducible results as possible. In the following code I am not sure if the order of the instructions for reproduciblity is correct.
I wonder if `os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']='0'` is in the right place, or should it appear first in the code, before `import numpy as np` etc.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random as rn

import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']='0'
np.random.seed(1)
rn.seed(1)

from keras import backend as K

if 'tensorflow' == K.backend():
  import tensorflow as tf
  from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
  config = tf.ConfigProto()
  config.gpu_options.allow_growth = true
  config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
  config.gpu_options.visible_device_liste = "0"
  set_session(tf.Session(config=config))

tf.set_random_seed(1) 
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)   
K.set_session(sess)   


!pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials 

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

I would be very happy and very thankful if someone could take a look at this code and could confirm the order as right or wrong.